# How to improve a case statement that uses two columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a table called Purchase which has a State column, where 1 is authorized, 2 is completed (there are some other values too).

I also have a Retailer table, which has a column RetailerProcessType, where 1 is one-step and 2 is two-step.

I have the query below:

```sql
CASE purc.State
    WHEN 1 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
    WHEN 2 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
    WHEN 4 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
    ELSE '"DECLINED"'
 END                                                                     
 AS Autorised_Decline_Status,
```

But what I need to do is as follows:

```sql
WHEN STATE = 2 AND RetailerProcessType = 1 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
WHEN STATE = 1 AND RetailerProcessType = 2 THEN '"PENDING"'
WHEN STATE = 2 AND RetailerProcessType = 2 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
ELSE '"DECLINED"'
```

The only way I can think of doing this is having a massive `IF` statement around the query, one for a one-step retailer and another for a two-step, as my understanding is a `WHEN` clause cannot have an `AND` in it.

However, this just seems long winded; anybody have any neater ideas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
-- Notice how STATE got moved inside the condition:
CASE WHEN STATE = 2 AND RetailerProcessType IN (1, 2) THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
     WHEN STATE = 1 AND RetailerProcessType = 2 THEN '"PENDING"'
     ELSE '"DECLINED"'
END
```

The reason you can do an `AND` here is that you are not checking the `CASE` of `STATE`, but instead you are CASING Conditions.

The key part here is that the `STATE` condition is a part of the `WHEN`.

Answer (score 9):

Just change your syntax ever so slightly:

```
CASE WHEN STATE = 2 AND RetailerProcessType = 1 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
     WHEN STATE = 1 AND RetailerProcessType = 2 THEN '"PENDING"'
     WHEN STATE = 2 AND RetailerProcessType = 2 THEN '"AUTHORISED"'
     ELSE '"DECLINED"'
END
```

If you don't put the field expression before the `CASE` statement, you can put pretty much any fields and comparisons in there that you want.  It's a more flexible method but has slightly more verbose syntax.