# How to write the equivalent SQL case statement for query given below?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my working query:

```
Query = "select Cust_Id,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New Where 1=1";
try
{
    if (txt_title.Text != "")
        Query += " and Clients_Title Like '%" + txt_title.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_address.Text != "")
        Query += " and Address_Current Like '%" + txt_address.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_phone.Text != "")
        Query += " and Phone_Number Like '%" + txt_phone.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_mobile.Text != "")
        Query += " and Mobile_Number Like '%" + txt_mobile.Text + "%'";
    if (cbo_location.Text != "")
        Query += " and AreaLocation Like '%" + cbo_location.Text + "%'";
}

catch { }
```

Here I am attempting to write its equivalent SQL case statement .

```
SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM Customer_New
    WHERE  1 = CASE WHEN @Clients_Title != " " THEN  Clients_Title  AND
                              WHEN  @Address_Current != " " THEN  Address_Current  AND
                             WHEN  @Phone_Number != " " THEN  Phone_Number AND
                             WHEN  @Mobile_Number != " " THEN  Mobile_Number AND
                             WHEN  @AreaLocation != " " THEN  AreaLocation 
END
```

Can any one correct my case statement?

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928474/sql-case-statement-when-statement-and-statement), think it may be of help

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it is evaluated to produce a *value*. It's not a statement, nor should it be thought of as some kind of control flow structure.

Comment: see this use of case statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730933/case-statement-in-where-clause-sql-server

Comment: you should update your question to include the requirement you expanded on in your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
    FROM            Customer_New
        where        (CASE
            WHEN @Clients_Title != ''   THEN Clients_Title=@Clients_Title
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @Address_Current != '' THEN Address_Current =@Address_Current
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
                  AND(CASE
            WHEN @Phone_Number != '' THEN Phone_Number=@Phone_Number
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @Mobile_Number != '' THEN Mobile_Number=@Mobile_Number
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @AreaLocation != '' THEN AreaLocation =@AreaLocation
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want this - no `CASE` required:

```
SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM Customer_New
    WHERE
      (@Clients_Title = '' OR Clients_Title LIKE '%'+@Clients_Title+'%') AND
      (@Address_Current = '' OR Address_Current LIKE '%'+@Address_Current+'%') AND
      (@Phone_Number = '' OR Phone_Number LIKE '%'+@Phone_Number+'%') AND
      (@Mobile_Number = '' OR Mobile_Number LIKE '%'+@Mobile_Number+'%') AND
      (@AreaLocation = '' OR AreaLocation LIKE '%'+@AreaLocation+'%')
```

Because that at least closely resembles your non-SQL code.

Comment: Error in WHERE clause near '"'.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Syntax looks fine on this SQL Fiddle I just knocked up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4e50e/1

Comment: Only working for this : SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM Customer_New  .....No where clause is working

Comment: I have seen usage of case statement from this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730933/case-statement-in-where-clause-sql-server

Comment: @getche won't work here, first you don't need a case here, second it would look really aweful, for example try to rephrase the first condition into a case: `Clients_Title = CASE WHEN @Clients_Title = '' THEN Clients_Title ELSE LIKE '%'+@Clients_Title+'%') END` but this won't work because as mentioned before, case just gets you `ONE VALUE` but in this case you would need it to get you `LIKE <concatenated string with a value>` with does not compute.

Comment: alright case will not work .....But your query is not fulfilling  the mentioned  requirements

Comment: What is needed in report viewers query is:

    When are all string of where clause are null then my report viewer
    should select query is:

    Query = "select Cust_Id,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New ";

    When any two string of where clause are not matching corresponding row db then nothing

will be displayed

    Lastly, selection will be made if just one condition of where clause is provided

Comment: @getche - `NULL` is *not* the same as an empty string, and this is the first time that `NULL` seems to have made an appearance in anything you've posted for this question. If you want to compare the variables to `NULL`, it should be `@Clients_Title IS NULL OR ...`